# Conditional menu items on Next.js 13.4 app directory

Tags: javascript, reactjs, components, next.js13

Everything seems different than the Next.js page directory! I have started a project using the latest Next.js such as App Directory/Routing but I am just able to work on the front end using this latest Next.js and I am just stacked into the API making and some conditional statements on JSX.

Look into my below codes:

In the `RootLayout`

```
export default async function RootLayout({ children }) {
    const user = await getCurrentUser();
    return (
        <html lang="en">
            <body suppressHydrationWarning={true}>
                <Navbar user={user} />
                {children}
                <Footer />
            </body>
        </html>
    );
}
```

And the user object below:

```
user: {
    id: 5,
    first_name: 'john',
    last_name: 'doe',
    email: 'john@gmail.com'
}
```

But in the Navbar component `({ user })` when I give a conditional logic for `Login & Logout` like below

```
{user && user.id ? (
    <button
        onClick={handleLogout}
    >
        Logout
    </button>
) : (
    <Link
        href="/auth/signin"
    >
        Login
    </Link>
)}
```

it seems not working such as always showing the `Login` either user presence or not.

I really do not understand what is going on here.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

i think you dont need set async your layout

`async function RootLayout`

you can try this , set function async in side function call your api with await ,

then call this function in useEffect()

```
    async function fetchUser() {
        const user = await getCurrentUser();
        setUser(user);
    }
    useEffect(() => {
    fetchUser();
}, []);
```

and you are need new component for clinet side rendering because u need useEffect()
then you can save result to sate or some where and pass data to other commponent

i hope this help .

Comment: The `RootLayout` is a server-side function, it's not supported by any client hooks.

Comment: yes but u can create other componet for client side , then use this componet to your RootLayout